# How to use in ngModel date but only month, year and date

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a interface with name Person and there is name, lastname, birthday and other variables. What is making me confused is in the person.birthday it is sending the date with some letters at the end.
What I want is to send the date in the store normaly date but when I want to show in the ngModel to show me only year, month, date.
Below you can find a code.

This is the code in HTMl

```
<app-input-field label="Gerbustag" labelWidth="105px">
            <input class="inputBackground" type="date" [(ngModel)]="person.birthday">
          </app-input-field>
```

This is the interface of the person.

```
export interface Person {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  birthday: Date;
```

What I have writed in the TS it is like this.

```
birthday = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
//This returns me good in the HTMl but this is not the correct birthday
```

Do you have any idea how can I show in html only year-month-date of the person

Comment: Have you tried using momentjs library? https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @niklaz that's not a solution, that's a library suggestion. As for the OP, could you make a [mcve] to show your issue ? Or at least show us what the console log gives, and what you are expecting ?

Comment: @trichetriche I can show in the console what is showing me and what I am expecting, I will my question in 2 minutes.

Comment: Okay, please notify me when you do so, I'm going on other questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use built in pipe for angular for dates.

1. {{ strDate | date :'hh:mm:ss' }} will give output 09:44:12
2. {{ strDate | date :'dd-MMM-yyyy' }} will give output 07-Nov-2016
3. {{ strDate | date :'h:mm' }} will give output 9:44
4. {{strDate | date :'dd:MMM:yyyy hh-mm-ss z'}} will give output 07:Nov:2016 09-44-12 India Standard Time
5. {{strDate | date :'hh:mm, E'}} will give output 09:44, Mon

See link , for more : 
  https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-date-pipe-example

usage :

```
 <input [ngModel]="person.birthday | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"  type="date" name="startDate"/>
```

Comment: Where to use this in the ngModel or in the closed input ?

Comment: I am facing with this issue.
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 19 in [person.birthday | date :'dd:MMM:yyyy'=$event]

Comment: i've edited my answer. use it as such. <input [ngModel]="person.birthday | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"  type="date" name="startDate"/>

Comment: It is working man because at ngModel I have done [(ngModel)] meanwhile should make [ngModel], I have make your answer as accepted

Comment: It is working to see, but when i make changes there it does not takes the changes with [ngModel] dou you have any idea how to do this ? when I change a date at input field

Comment: write a change function <input [ngModel]="person.birthday | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="startDate = $event" type="date" name="startDate"/>

Comment: I have changed at ngModelChange with 
ngModelChange="person.birthday = $event" and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In ngModel you can use it like this:

```
 var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
// expected output: Donnerstag, 20. Dezember 2012

console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('ko-KR', options));
// expected output: 2012년 12월 20일 목요일

var options2 = { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'};

console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options2));
// expected output: 18.6.2018
```